# 500 errors using Predis for session storage

Tags: php, session, redis, predis

I'm using Predis to store my PHP session data in Redis.

My site has pages which make multiple ajax calls, each of which will be authenticated in PHP by connecting to the Redis session store to look for a session variable.

I'm getting sporadic 500 errors, which I think may be due to the fact my PaaS will only allow 6 concurrent Redis connections. I think this because it happens most when I make >6 concurrent ajax calls.

Here's the typical error:

> [Fri Jul 26 17:25:53 2013] [error] [client 10.0.64.59] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Predis\Connection\ConnectionException' with message 'Error while writing bytes to the server [tcp://10.0.27.46:5058]' in /mnt/var/vcap.local/dea/apps/funnelplus-reports1-3-7416a344cc658624070a91d745d342d/app/_includes/Predis/Connection/AbstractConnection.php:139\nStack trace:\n#0 /mnt/var/vcap.local/dea/apps/funnelplus-reports1-3-77416a344cc658624070a91d745d342d/app/_includes/Predis/Connection/StreamConnection.php(189): Predis\Connection\AbstractConnection->onConnectionError('Error while wri...')\n#1 /mnt/var/vcap.local/dea/apps/funnelplus-reports1-3-77416a344cc658624070a91d745d342d/app/_includes/Predis/Connection/StreamConnection.php(294): Predis\Connection\StreamConnection->writeBytes('*4??$5??SETEX??...')\n#2 /mnt/var/vcap.local/dea/apps/funnelplus-reports1-3-77416a344cc658624070a91d745d342d/app/_includes/Predis/Connection/AbstractConnection.php(119): Predis\Connection\StreamConnection->writeCommand(Object(Predis\Command\StringSetExpire))\n#3 /mnt/var/vcap.local/dea/apps/funnelplus-reports1 in /mnt/var/vcap.local/dea/apps/funnelplus-reports1-3-77416a344cc658624070a91d745d342d/app/_includes/Predis/Connection/AbstractConnection.php on line 139, referer: http://www.domain.com/funnels?funnel=8

Is there a way to force Predis to queue these rather than simply throwing a 500, or a better way to authenticate these ajax calls?

I'm using Redis for sessions because the app is load balanced across multiple instances.

Comment: http://redis.io/topics/clients

Comment: Unfortunately I can't configure Redis - it's a PaaS provided service. I need to ensure my app handles the scenario better